# How do I reuse QueueClient instances to send response messages from Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-functions-runtime

The best practices article from Azure docs recommends reusing QueueClient to send multiple messages to obtain faster performance.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients

I have a scenario of request-response messaging where Azure function is sending responses after being triggered by a service bus queue trigger (which is a request message). 
The performance of QueueClient.SendAsync is slow (1.5 to 3 seconds) if I create a new QueueClient everytime the function executes.

If I reuse the QueueClient in a static variable then the SendAsync time reduces to 50ms for later calls. However, the static reference does not seem to be a reliable way of reusing QueueClient connection, since I do not know when to close it.

Is there a reliable way to reuse and then close the QueueClient across multiple function executions?
Can Azure-Function runtime provide any event where I can reliably close the queue client?

Answer (score 3):

I think the challenge here is that the Azure Function doesn't know when you are "done" sending messages.  If your Function has gone idle for sometime we may remove instances, but I don't believe there is any downside to doing a static QueueClient in a Function without ever explicitly closing it -- and it would be a best practice.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you switching to Service Bus output binding instead of sending messages manually with `QueueClient`. This way runtime will manage the instances of `QueueClient` and their configuration for you. See [Azure Functions Service Bus bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus), "Service Bus output binding" section.

Otherwise, static `QueueClient` as suggested by @jeffhollan is a viable option.